# Email functionality in cakephp 3.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

I have to implement send mail functionality by using normal php not Smtp in cakephp 3.5.

I have to send html testingreport.ctp that I have put under Template/Email/html.

Below I have added controller and app.php code.

I am getting error **Transport config "Mail" is missing.**

What I am missing here to send the mail?

```
//app.php
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Mail',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],
],
'Email' => [
    'default' => [
            'log' => true,
            'transport' => 'Mail',
            'emailFormat'=>'html',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ],
],


 // controller
$email = new Email('default');
    $email
    ->transport('testingreport','testingreport')
    ->from(['dkvastrakar18@gmail.com' => 'dkvastrakar18@gmail.com'])
    ->to('dkvastrakar18@gmail.com')
    ->subject('subjects')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->viewVars($testRequestDet)
    ->send('sendmail');
```

Answer (score 1):

The email profiles `transport` configuration option is ment to point to an entry in the `EmailTransport` configuration, not to an email transport class, the latter is configured via the `className` option in the specific transport configuration.

Long story short:

```
'transport' => 'Mail'
```

should be:

```
'transport' => 'default'
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Email > Configuration Profiles](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuration-profiles)**